# How to reproduce 'paste image' with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension, which can save and paste snippets.

Text items work great:

```
export function copyText(text: string): void {
  const textarea = window.document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textarea.style.opacity = '0';
  textarea.value = text;
  window.document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  window.document.execCommand('copy');
  window.document.body.removeChild(textarea);
}

export function pasteText(element: HTMLElement): void {
  element.focus();
  window.document.execCommand('paste');
}
```

Now, I'm trying to implement the same for images. When it works, this is how it looks at discord.com:

[image]

Currently, I'm stuck trying to reproduce this behavior (e.g. in Chrome console).

Do you have any idea how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's checking what you pasted. If it ends with an image format such as png, jpg, webp or avif. Then it will embed the url in an image element.

eg:_https://random.image/cute-dog.png would become

```html
<img src="https://random.image/cute-dog.png" />
```

Comment: How would you paste the image programatically?